# Is there a standard way to interact with my DPDK or C-program through cmdline on linux?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, udp, dpdk

I'm looking for a more "professional" way to interact with my programs written in C through command line(on linux).For example, when I want to modify the values of some of these variables during program runtime, what should I do?
Assume I want to modify values in program `cmd_ser`, I used to start a UDP **client** program `cmd_cli`, which sends UDP datagrams to a specific local port. Then `cmd_ser` will act like a UDP **server**, receives the datagram and parses values from it. 
To call `cmd_cli` by command, I added the executable binary, `cmd_cli.exe` to file:`~/.bashrc`, using `alias` to define a custom command — `cmd_cli`. Thus, once I execute cmd `cmd_cli para1 val1`, it calls `cmd_cli.exe` and send a UDP datagram to the local port.
Question is:

1. To consistently listen messages from local port, I'll have to start a **new thread** in my program `cmd_ser`, I was wondering if there were some more convenient and professional ways...
2. I would like to change the value during a new **DPDK program** runtime now, then I cannot use kernel networking APIs, is there som DPDK Lib APIs?(I'm totally rookie to DPDK and C programming, thanks!).

Comment: This is off-topic because it is not a specific programming question. There are many message-passing libraries that would simplify this task.

Comment: 1. Use nonblocking I/O and a single thread to handle all messages from the local port (see [poll()](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html)).  2. Use a parser/tokenizer to convert each message to one or more (name, value) pairs, and a hash table to map the name to a (type, pointer to value) pair.  Use [atomic built-ins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) to modify the values, so that other threads will always see either the old or the new value, never a combination; otherwise you'll need to protect the access to configuration values with a mutex.